# Homeomorphism is to topology as continuity is to

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

I have two questions.

1. Are there examples where continuity does not preserve connectedness?
2. Is there a structure whose structural properties are preserved by continuous map? (Just like homeomorphism is to topology.)

Comment: A continuous function always preserves connectedness

Comment: Well, $\mathbb R\to \mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto 42$ is continuous but the *range* is not connected even though the domain is. But of course the *image* is connected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No: it’s a theorem that continuous maps preserve connectedness.
2. No, assuming that *structure* includes cardinality: for any topological space $X$, no matter what extra structure it bears, the map from $X$ onto the one-point space is continuous.

Comment: Even though your answer to two is correct, with your added hypothesis, I would disagree with the premise that it's not structure preserving. It doesn't faithfully and completely preserve and project the structure, but surely, obviously, it preserves some of the structure (e.g. connectedness of image) etc.

Answer (score 3):

Continuity always preserves connectedness. (But not disconnectedness)

In the category of topological spaces and continuous maps, homeomorphisms are the isomorphisms. The idea here is the continuous maps preserve topological structures, but homeomorphisms are the type of continuous functions you use to show that two topological spaces are the "same".